# Where is the $m$ in $e=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-V'^2}}?$ (Schwarzschild)

Tags: general-relativity, energy

We are in the Schwarzschild geometry.

Consider a stone of mass $m$ that is thrown radially towards the centre of a black hole from a starting point with large radial separation (assume $r\to \infty$). Let the initial velocity as measured by a stationary observer at infinity, be $V'$.

I want to show that, 
$$e=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-V'^2}},$$
which is apparently correct.

Why is this not actually

$$e=\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-V'^2}}?$$

Something to do with being in the Schwarschild geometry and being at $r\to \infty$?

Comment: what does $e$ stand for?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin Energy

Comment: Where did you get the formula? Have you derived this yourself?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin Past exam: 2014 - university of queensland

Comment: It is probably energy per unit mass. Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are at infinity, then you are in flat space. So , as usual

$$E=mc^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(V'/c)^2}},$$

Energy per unit mass $e$, with $c=1$ then gives

$$e=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-V'^2}},$$

as stated.